# Excel fill table based on 3 criteria

Tags: excel

i have a list which Had been exported from a software, but i need to get it to create a report based on multiple criteria, (time cells have the date and time included).
[image]
I need the information to be put in a new table filtered by the specific PERSP_CODE, see sample below (not real based in the blue data)
[image]
i tried multiple things but i cannot wrap my head around as the times are exported in a very disorienting manner :/

thank you in advance!

Match, XLookup, Index match, match multiple criteria

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the initial table to power query Data>From Table
Select first three columns (empid, pers_code,page) and select unpivot other columns.
Format if needed the single value column that will be created as time

Close & Load to pivot table and then i believe you got it you can group the data in a tabular design pivot to have in the rows the three columns we fixed in the beginning and group the times in hours let say so that you can provide a proper report to whoever needs to get it.